# Get elements of a list with the same name in R

Tags: r, database, list, dataframe

I have a list of elements where several elements have the same name (i.e. Name or S)

This a part of the list:

```
> str(MKtf)
List of 160
 $ Name        : chr "S09489500"
 $ S           : num 0
 $ Var         : num 34147
 $ Z           : num 0
 $ Significance: chr "X"
 $ Name        : chr "S09489499"
 $ S           : num -1
 $ Var         : num 4957
 $ Z           : num 0
 $ Significance: chr "X"
 $ Name        : chr "S09511300"
 $ S           : num 1
 $ Var         : num 11890
 $ Z           : num 0
 $ Significance: chr "X"
 $ Name        : chr "S09498400"
 $ S           : num 0
 $ Var         : num 7367
 $ Z           : num 0
 $ Significance: chr "X"
 $ Name        : chr "S09498500"
 $ S           : num 0
 $ Var         : num 134177
```

How is possible to access all the elements of the list with the same name? for example I want to get all the elements ($S)  of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
MKtf[names(MKtf) == "S"]
```

Using a reproducible example :

```
MKtf <- list(S = 1:4, B = 2:3, S = 4:5, B = 21:23)
MKtf[names(MKtf) == "S"]

#$S
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#$S
#[1] 4 5
```